# Coloring result in terminal for ruby test/unit

Tags: ruby, unit-testing

I am running some test in pure ruby using the `test/unit`, but the result I see in the command line is ugly, and with no colors(green for success and red for failure). How can I make that possible? I am using mac, and I am running the test on a single ruby file that contains some methods

Answer (score 0):

I have partially solved this issue by using `ruby.2.2` instead of the old versions of ruby